# set-header for HAProxy when Content-Type" is missing from headers

Tags: haproxy

I am using haproxy as a load balancer. For one of our back end services, example abc, if "Content-Type" is missing from headers, we need to add the header "Content-Type" with value as "application/json" at HA-proxy level.

I am unable to find the solution for same.

Answer (score 4):

You could have used a search engine?

```
 http-response set-header Content-Type application/json
```

If you want this only when there's no Content-Type

```
acl no_ct res.hdr(Content-Type) -m len 0
http-response set-header Content-Type application/json if no_ct
```

If the backend used the CONTENTTYPE header but you need Content-Type:

```
acl bad_ct res.hdr(CONTENTTYPE) -m found
http-response set-header Content-Type %[req.hdr(CONTENTTYPE)] if bad_ct
```

Comment: Thanks, Gerard for your suggestion. And i also need that if in a header if we get CONTENTTYPE like this, it must be changed to Content-Type. I would great if you can help this.

Comment: In that case, just remove the "if no_ct" ?  Or will the CONTENTTYPE header have another value than "application/json"?